# SOAPUI: SImple Groovy script - syntax error on import statement?

Tags: javascript, groovy, soapui

Very new to scripting and the SOAPUI DOM, and have a problem that's foxing me.

A while ago, I copied some sample code and modified it to prompt the user for a value in a test step.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.*
def alert = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport
def userVenue = alert.prompt("Venue","Webservices-UserName")
// get properties from testCase, testSuite and project
def testSuiteProperty = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "UVenID" )
// setting values is equally straight forward
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "UVenID", userVenue)
```

This has all been working quite happily for a while now. Until this week. The exact same code now throws a javascript exception: "org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: syntax error"

Investigation shows this to be thrown by the import statement. If I remove the import statement, I get a different error (of course), "missing ; before statement"

I'm totally stumped as, as far as I'm aware, nothing has changed. Java was last updated in April (Java 8 update 45), SOAPUI is the 5.0.0 free version running on Win 8.1.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Why is javascript trying to evaluate a groovy script?

Comment: yep, looks like you are feeding groovy to a javascript evaluator, and that evaluator is right to complain about imports and missing semicolons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 3 soapUI allows us to use Javascript instead of Groovy. In the Project properties section there is a script language option, check if that option has javascript as the selected value of groovy.

Also see http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/scripting-and-the-script-library.html for details specifically section 4.

[image]

*Image source is the soapUI link mentioned earlier.

Comment: Many thanks! I told you I was new to all this!  The change didn't take immediately, I had to stop and restart SOAPUI, but it's all back to 'what passes for normal here now.

Comment: Thats correct you'll have to restart soapUI for it to take effect. Same as adding a JAR to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch your project language interpreter back to Groovy. In Project Properties, under the Scripting Language is a pull down that changes this. Detailed instructions are in the [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/scripting-and-the-script-library.html#4-JavaScript-support).